# what is the meaning of the first line in every files in the SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

```
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');
```

What is the meaning of the line which occurs every first line of the file in the SugarCRM.

Answer (score 6):

SugarCRM loads nearly all functionality through index.php, so you see URIs crafted like `index.php?module=Accounts&action=index` throughout the system.

Most SugarCRM versions define `sugarEntry` (a [PHP Constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)) in the very first line of index.php, right after the PHP opener. This tells later files in the application that your browser request did indeed first request index.php.

The logic on that line literally states: If `sugarEntry` was not defined, or was set to false, then call [PHP die()](https://www.php.net/die) terminate the execution of the script.

What this directly prohibits is the ability to load /modules/Accounts/ListView.php and similar commands, which would call a file directly and not correctly load the underlying classes and functions to display the page properly. It also enforces some security and structure of the system.

### Other Valid sugarEntry points

`cron.php` is the entry point to the system that executes scheduled jobs and is typically accessed by a Linux system's cron or Windows' Task Scheduler. `run_job.php` seems to be similar, though I've never seen this invoked or used, so it may be a legacy piece.

`soap.php` is a legacy entry point to the SOAP API

`services/*/rest.php` and `services/*/soap.php` are valid entry points to various versions of the more current SOAP and REST APIs.

The point is that there are a very limited ways to "get in" to SugarCRM, and the software wants to be very explicit about which paths are allowed and which are not.